# Set interval to ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

So I'm trying to send the form info to php with ajax form every second, but for some reason it doesn't want to.

Here is my latest attempt, I tried every other similar combination(like put everything in the function or just put everything into the setInterval).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ajaxCall=function() {
        $("#myForm").ajaxForm(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'php1.php',
                data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
                success:function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=data;
                }
            });
        });
    }
    setInterval(ajaxCall,1000);
});
```

EDIT

Solved with M.M answer, thank you for the help!

Comment: Does `ajaxCall()` work if you don't call it from `setInterval()`?

Comment: You should accept his answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simply change `ajaxForm` to `ajaxSubmit`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form) (question) and [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) (documentation) for more information on AjaxForm vs AjaxSubmit

Essentially AjaxForm submits when the user clicks the button and AjaxSubmit does it immediately so your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ajaxCall=function()
    {
    $("#myForm").ajaxSubmit(function(e)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:'post',
            url:'php1.php',
            data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=data;
            }
        });
    });
    }
    setInterval(ajaxCall,1000);
});
```

---

#### Update after comment explanation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //live feed
    var ajaxCall=function(){
        $("#myForm").ajaxSubmit(function(e){
            ajax_submit();
        });
    }
    setInterval(ajaxCall,1000);

    //real submit
    $("#myForm").ajaxForm(function(e){
        ajax_submit();
    });

    function ajax_submit(){//ajax_code
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'php1.php',
            data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=data;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### If you wish to differentiate the feed from the submit you can pass a parameter to the `ajax_submit` function

Comment: it works really nice that way, but in my case i really need to press the submit button because I have an option list. Any way I can do it with ajaxForm?

Comment: Walk me through it, is the user supposed to submit the form once and you need to read the information every second?

Comment: yes, it's some kind of remote access to Linux, so the user selects one command (ex. ifconfig) and it should give him a live feed of that.

Comment: So i suggest you separate the actions, one function to check the submition and another to receive the info, I'll update my answer

Comment: @BoantaIonut if this answer truly solved your problem consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the ajaxForm() call seems to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ajaxCall = function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'php1.php',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
        }
      });
  }
  setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, if you see my answer you'll understand why